# What is the difference between Extends and New in Java?

Tags: java

Say you have a class called superclass.

I can say

```
Public class MyClass extends superclass
```

and i can do

```
superclass sc = new superclass();
```

both methods let me use methods/variables in that class. can someone make the picture a little bit more clear?

Comment: One defines a new class which is a superset of the functionality of `superclass`. The other creates an **instance** of `superclass`.

Comment: But what does the first one give me that the second one doesn't? i can't really see the difference. In addition to this, inheritance from multiple classes isn't possible. Extends can only take one class and i cant do it multiple times in a class

Comment: A `class` defines how an *instance* will behave. To do any work you need to instantiate an object using the `new` keyword. Extending a class is a way to modify how the instance will operate during runtime. You can add fields and methods that the base class may not have

Comment: first gives you a new Class(A new "Type" ) and second just creates an instance (sets a concrete variable of this type)

Comment: and btw, your code won't compile: if you try to make it compile, that may help you with your question as well.

Comment: Starting with the intro sections in the Java Tutorial should help - What is a Class? What is an Object? What is inheritance? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

Answer (score 2):

So there is a misunderstanding about what a class is and what an instance is. Every object in Java is defined by a class. The class is a set of fields and methods which defines how an instance of the class behaves.

Say you have a class `Foo`

```
class Foo {
    int foo() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

To call `foo` I need to create an instance of the class.

```
Foo f = new Foo();
System.out.println(f.foo());
```

One reason that instantiating a class is useful, is because you can create multiple objects which act slightly differently. Take for example this modified version of `Foo`

```
class Foo {
    int i;
    Foo(int i) {
        this. i = i;
    }
    int foo() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

In this example I add a field to `Foo` called `i` and a constructor to set `i`. I can now instantiate `Foo` with different values of `i`.

```
Foo f1 = new Foo(1);
Foo f2 = new Foo(2);
System.out.println(f1.foo());
System.out.println(f2.foo());
// prints 1 2
```

When you extend a class you can update, add, or override the methods from `Foo`

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    Bar(int i) {
        super(i); // call Foo's constructor too
    }
    int bar() {
        return i * 2;
    }
}
```

Notice how I can still use the method `foo`, but also use the extra method `bar`:

```
Bar b = new Bar(3);
System.out.println(b.foo());
System.out.println(b.bar());
// prints 3 6
```